# Проиграть анимацию один раз

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Есть тип врага, подходя к которому, он должен выпускать в меня снаряд, соответственно должна проигрываться анимация атаки, потом задержка в пару секунд (во время задержки переключаться на анимацию покоя), потом опять атака и так далее. Есть ли какой метод для того чтобы запустить анимацию 1 раз? Или какое-нибудь другое решение этой проблемы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class EnemyMagicPatrool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool enemyDead = false;
    public float health = 100;
    [Space(15)]
    public Transform target;
    public float engaugeDistance = 10f;
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;
    [Space(15)]
    private bool facingLeft = true;
    [Space(15)]
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    new CapsuleCollider2D collider;
    // isGrounded
    public bool isGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;

    private bool isGroundedFlip;
    public Transform groundCheckFlip;
    public LayerMask whathIsGroundFlip;
    public LayerMask whathIsGround;
    [Space(15)]
    public Vector3 direct;
    //  public PersControll persControll;
    //  [HideInInspector]
    public Transform bar;
    //   [HideInInspector]
    public GameObject destroyHP;

    private float timeByAttack = 2;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        direct = target.position - this.transform.position;
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(new Vector2(groundCheck.position.x - 0.1f, groundCheck.position.y - 0.1f), new Vector2(groundCheck.position.x + 0.1f, groundCheck.position.y + 0.1f), whathIsGround);

        LostHp();

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            rb.mass = 350f;
            rb.angularDrag = 50f;                        // ------------ подреглировать физику
            anim.SetBool("isDead", true);
            collider.direction = CapsuleDirection2D.Horizontal;
            collider.offset = new Vector2(1f, -2f);
            collider.size = new Vector2(5f, 0.5f);
            enemyDead = true;
            Invoke("Dead", 5f);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!isGrounded && !enemyDead)   
            {
                anim.SetBool("isJump", true);
                anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
                anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                Debug.DrawLine(target.position, this.transform.position, Color.green);
            }
            else
            {
                if (isGrounded && !enemyDead && (direct.x < 10f && direct.x > -10f) && (direct.y < 2f && direct.y > -2f)) // если в зоне агро
                {

                    anim.SetTrigger("isAttackingTr");
                    //anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
                    //anim.SetBool("isIdle", false);
                    //anim.SetBool("isJump", false);
                }
                else if (isGrounded && !enemyDead && ((direct.x > 10f || direct.x < -10f) || (direct.y > 2f || direct.y < -2f))) // вне зоны агро
                {
                    anim.SetTrigger("isIdleTr");
                    //anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
                    //anim.SetBool("isJump", false);
                    //anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void Dead()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    void LostHp()
    {
        if (health > 0)
        {
            bar.localScale = new Vector3(health / 100f, 1f);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(destroyHP);
        }
    }
    public void Flip()
    {
        facingLeft = !facingLeft;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

        theScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вашей проблемой занимались, то код нужен текстом, а не картинкой, чтобы его можно было "пощупать".

Comment: Все добавил код

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, под "анимация должна проигрываться 1 раз"? То есть после атаки с анимацией и покоя, когда враг будет атаковать второй раз, то анимация атаки не должна проигрываться? Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: атака -> покой -> атака -> покой ....
можно ли каким встроенным методом запустить анимацию на 1 раз? конкретно тут это будет анимация атаки

Comment: я в принципе уже решил через несколько Invoke(), 
но что то мне подсказывает что я такой костыль создал.

Comment: через несколько Invoke(){anim.SetTriger("QWERTY");}

Comment: @ВалентинСтарцев если зададите анимации Idle время 2 секунды (или сколько должен перс ждать до следующей атаки?) и в аниматоре настроите такой переход от Idle в Slashing, который будет ждать окончания Idle, то вы получите такой результат: из Idle, по получению триггера "атакуй" (из кода), перейдёт в анимацию атаки, по её окончанию выйдет из неё и как минимум 1 раз полностью проиграет анимацию Idle (т.е. ваши 2 секунды), затем уже, если триггер атаки снова установлен, снова перейдёт в атаку.
Вообще, по моему мнению, данная проблема у вас из-за неудачного кода. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую так сделать. А про код полностью согласен, я его буду переделывать, это я так, учусь пока что.